# Can systemd-boot load a kernel from an arbitrary partition?

Tags: systemd, systemd-boot

I have a disk with three paritions: a boot partition (with systemd-boot), root file system 1, and root file system 2

In past embedded systems I've done, I've stored the kernel for each of these file systems on those file systems (not on the boot partition), and u-boot was able to load whichever one I wanted.

I can't find a way to duplicate this behavior using systemd-boot.  Can systemd-boot only load kernels from the same partition on which it booted?

As an example, here is my current boot entry:

```
title boot
linux /bzImage
options LABEL=boot  rootwait console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 psplash=false
```

I want to effectively change that linux line to:

`linux {/dev/mmcblk1p2}/boot/bzImage`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, systemd-boot uses EFI file system drivers to load the kernel and initrd instead of bringing its own, and only ever accesses the EFI System Partition.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  You're saying it's possible to load the kernel off a different partition?  If so, how do I specify which partition the kernel is on?  In my case, systemd-boot is loading off of ```/dev/mmcblk1p1``` and I want to grab a kernel off of ```/dev/mmcblk1p2``` or ```/dev/mmcblkp3```.

Comment: In theory, it could load the kernel from another DOS partition, in practice it expects them in a specific directory on the EFI partition.